# Jackson: Serialize/deserialize with different property name

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have this POJO:

```
public class SetPoint {

    private String tagName;
    //more fields

   //getters and setters

}
```

I'm getting SetPoints from a REST API, do something with them and then send them again. Problem is that I want deserialize a SetPoint from a JSON like:

```
{
    "tagnameOpc" : "6GH783",
    //more fields
}
```

But when I send them, I want serialize a SetPoint as:

```
{
    "tagName" : "6GH783"
    //more fields
}
```

I mean, I want the property `tagName` to be named different in each case.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a different `JsonProperty` annotation for the getter and the setter. E.g.

```
@JsonProperty("tagnameOpc")
void setTagName(String name)

@JsonProperty("tagName")
String getTagName()
```

If that doesn't work try with an extra setter

```
@JsonIgnore
void setTagName(String name)

@JsonProperty("tagnameOpc")
void setTagNameOpc(String name) {
    setTagName(name);
}

@JsonProperty("tagName")
String getTagName()
```

Comment: Setters are for Deserialization of a Json string to an object. They make non-public fields deserializable. Getters are for Serialization of an object to Json. They make non-public fields serializable

Answer (score 1):

Jackson [mix-in annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) might help.

You would use the `SetPoint` class twice, but write a different mix-in class for each serialisation/deserialisation format, and then configure the ObjectMapper separately for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jsonObject is a JSONObject containing your json:

```
jsonObject.put("tagName", jsonObject.remove("tagnameOpc"));
```

From [JSonObject documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove(java.lang.String)): `jsonObject.remove(key)` returns the value that was associated with that key, or null if there was no value.

Comment: I'm using `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with Spring RestTemplate, so actually I don't work directly with `JSONObject`. Thanks, anyway